# encoding "John wants to bite Sara" in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to figure out how you would encode "[agent A] wants to [verb] to [agent B]" as first-order logic (e.g. "John wants to bite Sara").

To encode "John bites Sara" as FOL would be: `bites(John, Sara)` or if you like `John(x) ^ Sara(y) ^ bites(x,y)`.

Also, something I noticed is that this relationship could be recursive. for example:

- "John wants to want to bite Sara" (John wants to have the desire to bite Sara)
- "John wants to want to want to bite Sara" (John wants to be in the state such that he wants to want to bite Sara).

Does anyone know how I can handle this, particularly the sentence "John wants to bite Sara".

Answer (score 2):

Tricky!

Let's first make the structure of the sentence more clear: "John wants that he bites Sara". The "he" of course refers to John, so we can simplify to:

- "John wants that John bites Sara"

Now we can try to formulate this using a predicate, as before:

- wants(John, "John bites Sara")

But then the 2nd argument would be a **sentence**, rather than a term denoting some object like "John" or "Sara". It turns out, your sentence cannot be formalized using just predicates in FOL, because "wants that" is not a relation between individuals (like "bites(x,y)"), but a relation between an individual (John) and a sentence/proposition ("John bites Sara").

"John wants that `A`" is a *sentential operator*: It takes some sentence `A` and forms a new sentence with it. Other examples of operators that take sentences and make new sentences are "`A` and `B`", "ìf `A`, then `B`", "not `A`", or "it is necessary that `A`".

So "John wants that `A`" is "on the same level" as the logical operators in FOL. If we want to formalize sentences of the form "`x` wants that `A`", we need to extend the logic by adding an additional operator (for each `x`). This requires a step to intensional semantics (e.g. possible-worlds semantics), because the meaning of "`x` wants that `A`" cannot be specified using a truth-table alone (as with "not `A`" or "`A` and `B`").

[Epistemic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/) ([click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic#Epistemic_logic)), for example, is propositional logic, extended by sentential operators `B_x(A)`, `K_x(A)` that represent "`x` *believes* that `A`" and "`x` *knows* that `A`".